# Grand Total Calculation Issue in Dynamic HTML Table with Quantity Input

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am facing a problem with the Grand Total calculation in a dynamic HTML table where rows can be added, removed, and quantities can be adjusted. The issue arises when a new row is added or a row is removed; the Grand Total does not update correctly unless the quantity is manually increased.

Here's a brief overview of the functionality:

- Products can be added to the table from a datalist.
- Quantity input for each product allows adjustment.
- Rows can be removed with a "Remove" button.

The Grand Total is expected to update dynamically with each modification to the table, but there seems to be an issue in the JavaScript code that handles the calculation.

```js
// Initial check when the page loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("productTable").style.display = "none";
});

function addProductRow() {
  document.getElementById("productTable").style.display = "table";
  var productInput = document.getElementById("product");
  var productName = productInput.value;

  if (productName.trim() !== "") {
    var productDataList = document.getElementById("products");
    var selectedOption = [...productDataList.options].find(option => option.value === productName);
    updateGrandTotal();

    if (selectedOption) {
      var productPrice = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-price");
      var tableBody = document.getElementById("productTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

      var row = tableBody.insertRow();
      row.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${productName}</td>
                    <td>$${productPrice}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" value="1" oninput="updateSubtotal(this); updateGrandTotal();">
                    </td>
                    <td class="subtotal">$${productPrice}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="remove-button" onclick="removeProductRow(this)">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                `;

      productInput.value = ""; // Clear the product input after adding a row
      updateGrandTotal();
    }
  }
}

function removeProductRow(button) {
  var row = button.parentElement.parentElement;
  row.parentElement.removeChild(row);
  updateGrandTotal();

  //Check if there are no products
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("productTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  if (tableBody.rows.length < 2) {
    document.getElementById("productTable").style.display = "none";
  }

  updateGrandTotal();
}

function updateSubtotal(input) {
  var quantity = parseInt(input.value);
  var unitPriceCell = input.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  var unitPrice = parseFloat(unitPriceCell.textContent.replace('$', ''));
  var row = input.parentElement.parentElement;

  var subtotalCell = row.querySelector('.subtotal');
  var subtotal = quantity * unitPrice;
  subtotalCell.textContent = `$${subtotal}`;
  updateGrandTotal();
}

function updateGrandTotal() {
  var tableBody = document.getElementById("productTable").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var grandTotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    //console.log("rows length :", rows.length)
    //console.log("i value:", i); // Log the value

    var subtotalCell = rows[i].querySelector('.subtotal');
    //console.log("Sub Total Cell :", rows.length)

    grandTotal += parseInt(subtotalCell.textContent.replace('$', '')) || 0;

    //console.log("grand total :", grandTotal)

    //console.log("")

  }

  var grandTotalRow = document.getElementById("grandTotalRow");
  if (grandTotalRow) {
    grandTotalRow.parentElement.removeChild(grandTotalRow);
  }

  grandTotalRow = tableBody.insertRow();
  grandTotalRow.id = "grandTotalRow";
  grandTotalRow.className = "grand-total-row";
  grandTotalRow.innerHTML = `
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td align="right"><strong>Grand Total:</strong></td>
            <td class="subtotal" id="grandTotalValue">$${grandTotal}</td>
            <td></td>
        `;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table id="productTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Sub-Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <label for="product">Product name:</label>
  <input list="products" name="product" id="product" oninput="addProductRow()">
  <datalist id="products">
    <option value="Product 1" data-price="25">
    <option value="Product 2" data-price="30">
    <option value="Product 3" data-price="15">
    <option value="Product 4" data-price="22">
  </datalist>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. I had to add a `<form>` to make it valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend delegation

Here is a rewrite. Note I moved the grandTotal to a static tfoot and added a productPrice class to the cell that holds the price

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const table = document.getElementById("productTable")
  table.hidden = true;
  const tableBody = document.querySelector("#productTable tbody");
  const productDataList = document.getElementById("products");
  const productInput = document.getElementById("product");
  const grandTotal = document.getElementById("grandTotalValue");
  const updateGrandTotal = () => {
    const rows = tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr');
    table.hidden = rows.length === 0;
    if (rows.length === 0) return;
    const total = [...rows].map(row => +row.querySelector('.subtotal').textContent.trim().slice(1)).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    grandTotal.textContent = `${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  };
  const updateSubtotal = (input) => {
    var quantity = parseInt(input.value);
    const row = input.closest('tr');
    var unitPrice = +row.querySelector('.productPrice').textContent.trim().slice(1);
    var subtotalCell = row.querySelector('.subtotal');
    var subtotal = quantity * unitPrice;
    subtotalCell.textContent = `$${subtotal}`;
    updateGrandTotal();
  };

  const addProductRow = () => {
    table.hidden = false;
    var productName = productInput.value;
    if (productName.trim() === "") return;
    var selectedOption = [...productDataList.options].find(option => option.value === productName);
    if (selectedOption) {
      var productPrice = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-price");
      tableBody.innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td>${productName}</td>
        <td class="productPrice">$${productPrice}</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" value="1" "></td>
        <td class="subtotal">$${productPrice}</td>
        <td><button class="remove-button">Remove</button></td>
      </tr>`;
      productInput.value = ""; // Clear the product input after adding a row
    }
  };
  tableBody.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.matches("input[name=quantity]")) {
      updateSubtotal(tgt);
      updateGrandTotal();
    }
  });
  tableBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('button.remove-button');
    if (!tgt) return;
    tgt.closest('tr').remove();
    updateGrandTotal();
  });
  productInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    addProductRow();
    updateGrandTotal();
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <table id="productTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Sub-Total</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>Grand Total:</strong></td>
      <td class="subtotal" id="grandTotalValue">$0.00</td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <label for="product">Product name:</label>
  <input list="products" name="product" id="product">
  <datalist id="products">
    <option value="Product 1" data-price="25">
    <option value="Product 2" data-price="30">
    <option value="Product 3" data-price="15">
    <option value="Product 4" data-price="22">
  </datalist>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the grand total but introduced a bug for sub-totals where it's not responsive to value increase or decrease. I will mention it in another answer due to character limits.

Comment: @z_ahamed My bad. I have added a class to the second cell to get the price easily. It seems not necessary to look through the datalist to find the price already stored in the same row

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @mplungjan worked. The Grand total was updated properly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77598801/14238946

But it introduced a bug for sub-totals where it's not responsive to value increase or decrease. Modifying the `updateSubtotal` part solved it. Instead of getting the unit price from the `.subtotal` cell, it should be obtained from the corresponding product row.-

```
const updateSubtotal = (input) => {
            const row = input.closest('tr');
            const productName = row.querySelector('td:first-child').textContent;
            const selectedOption = [...productDataList.options].find(option => option.value === productName);
            if (selectedOption) {
                const unitPrice = +selectedOption.getAttribute("data-price");
                const quantity = parseInt(input.value);
                const subtotalCell = row.querySelector('.subtotal');
                const subtotal = quantity * unitPrice;
                subtotalCell.textContent = `$${subtotal}`;
                updateGrandTotal();
            }
        };
```

Comment: See my update. It seems not necessary to look through the datalist to find the price already stored in the same row